# SQL - Find values within a string on vendor table and match that value to customer table to fetch account number

Tags: sql-server

Went and read through a lot of posts but didn't find an answer to my problem. A have a list of a bout 12K records that a vendor f***d up... lets call it 'vendor_table'. The column I'm working with (Title) contains a long string with various values. Within that string however, lies the full customer name (in the format [last name, first name]). What I want to do is find the customer name in the string and then using my customer table fetch the customer ID. Let me provide some samples for clarity.

**vendor_table**

```
Title
```

1. (2016) (1)_Doe, John_141 0803...
2. Empire 12345 st va Doe, Marie CA..

**customer_table**

```
Cust_Name         Cust_ID
```

1. Doe, Jack........         12345
2. Doe, Marie.......        98765
3. Doe, John........         43456

**This is where I want to get**

```
Title                                       Cust_ID
```

1. (2016) (1)_Doe, John_141 0803...................43456
2. Empire 12345 st va Doe, Marie CA...............98765

Please help. How do I do this in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Thats not really good database design, because there is no relation between the two tables. Please consider adding the Cust_Name into the vendor_table as separat column - this will be the minimum to fix the situation, so that you could join with select * from vendor_table vt, customer_table ct where vt.Cust_Name = ct.Cust_Name

Comment: Thanks Yogesh... forgot to add the DBMS I use. Hi Power... the list was given to me by a vendor in Excel.. I just imported it into SQL server and was tasked to add the customer ID. I have nothing else to work with.

Comment: you can work with regular expressions, and search for a section(Word, Word), but if the section occurs more times in the string, then you have little chance

Comment: The only possibility I see, is to use the ',' and get all the alpha characters before and after it to create another Cust_Name column and then establish a relationship between the two tables. The name only occurs once in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INSERT INTO VENDOR_TABLE VALUES('(2016) (1)_Doe, John_141 0803')
INSERT INTO VENDOR_TABLE VALUES('Empire 12345 st va Doe, Marie CA')

CREATE TABLE customer_table(ID INT ,TITLE NVARCHAR(300))

INSERT INTO customer_table VALUES(43456,'Doe, John')
INSERT INTO customer_table VALUES(98765,'Doe, Marie')

SELECT v.TITLE,c.ID FROM VENDOR_TABLE V
,customer_table C
WHERE CHARINDEX(C.TITLE,V.TITLE)>1

Comment: hmmm charindex... interesting... let me give it a try... thanks Sumo.